# sass is broken "'dart.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: sass

I have received this error:

> 'dart.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program > or batch file.

Sass was working one day, but the next it stopped and gave me this error, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling. What could the issue be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install Dart. Check this out:

https://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk#install

or this

https://katiek2.github.io/path-doc/

or this

https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass

Answer (score 2):

Please **Update your Package manager**.

example : you use chocolatey Package manager

```
choco update sass
```

Then your Dart Dependencies will Updated

Finally it will be work...!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the exact same error. I found that I had to run the Command Prompt as administrator and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Going between Mac and PC, I ran into this after mistakenly downloading the .zip file for Mac when I was on PC.  No .exe files in the Mac version!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after searching a lot.

Before downloading flutter from

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install

Disable your antivirus.

Then move the folder to C: and add the exception for the antivirus you are using.

Remember to add to ENV path:

and value as

```
C:\Windows\System32
C:\Program Files\Git
C:\flutter\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use WSL on Windows 10, don't configure flutter from WSL's command prompt. Clean the flutter repo, configure everything from PowerShell and then it will hopefully work.